# is there a way for me to shorten my code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a possible solution for me to shorten this code? It looks redundant. Thank you!

```
let sanitizedFirstName = sanitize(firstName).trim()
let sanitizedLastName = sanitize(lastName).trim()
let sanitizedEducationalBackground = sanitize(educationalBackground).trim()
let sanitizedAddress = sanitize(address).trim()
let sanitizedRole = sanitize(role).trim()
let sanitizedEmail = sanitize(email).trim()
let sanitizedPassword = sanitize(password).trim()
let sanitizedFarmAddress = sanitize(farmAddress).trim()
```

Comment: There are ways to shorten it, but I would suggest that keeping it simple is more valuable than saving characters.

Comment: I see. So, my first code was good rather than using such like destructuring?

Comment: You didn't explain how do you want to use those variables in your code. The answer depends mainly on that. Destructuring can be overkill, it does make sense only in certain cases, not all of them. So the answers you received might not be optimal.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific. Those variables were meant to be used to store in the database because they were sanitized using the sanitize-html npm package.

Comment: Obligatory warning: Don't trust anything that comes from the client, whether it should have been sanitised or not. (If you're doing this in server-side JS, you can ignore this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use destructure.

```
const [sanitizedFirstName, sanitizedLastName, sanitizedEducationalBackground] = [firstName, lastName, educationalBackground].map(x => sanitize(x).trim())
```

However, I will still recommend use variable more clear to read an maintain.

Sample:

```js
const sanitize = (str = "") => str.replace(/\W+/g, "-");
console.log(sanitize("Test me"));

const [firstName, lastName, fullName] = ["Deepak V", "Vish@@", "Deepak V Visha@@"].map(sanitize)
console.log([firstName, lastName, fullName])
```

Or you can create a util function, can sanitize whole object. refer below example.

```
const sanitizeObject = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((m, [key, value]) => {
    m[key] = sanitize(value);
    return m;
  }, {});
```

```js
const sanitize = (str = "") => str.replace(/\W+/g, "-");
const sanitizeObject = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((m, [key, value]) => {
    m[key] = sanitize(value);
    return m;
  }, {});
const person = {
  firstName: "Deepak, R",
  lastNam: "V Vis",
  address: "356 $hhshshs",
  age: 30,
  salary: 200,
};
const sanitizedPartial = sanitizeObject({
  firstName: person.firstName,
  lastNam: person.lastNam,
  address: person.address,
});
const updatedPerson = {
  ...person,
  ...sanitizedPartial,
};
console.log(updatedPerson);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! The use of destructuring was quite handy.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to put vars in array and loop them:

```js
[firstName, lastName, ..., farmAddress].forEach(funciton (name) {
   window['sanitized' + (name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1))] = sanitize(name).trim()
});
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice...
1) window or any other global variable shouldn't be used
2) do not store properties dynamically like ```obj['abc'+xyz]``` when it's not strictly needed. You are making too many assumptions ... You can override something without knowing it or you can create a monster like 'sanitizedundefinednull'. 3) thousands of other possible side effects